# Pythagorean triples in Haskell using infinities lists

Tags: haskell

I want to generate pythagorean triples in Haskell using infinities lists. What's wrong with my code:

```
trojkaty = [(a,b,c) | a <- [1..], b <- [1..], c <- [1..], (a^2)+(b^2)==(c^2)]
```

Comment: FYI, not the most efficient code [use linear algebra](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tree_of_primitive_Pythagorean_triples)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try expressing the upper bounds for `a` and `b` in terms of the intermediate value of `c`, otherwise it will force all the entire list of infinite values before checking the last condition.

```
trojkaty :: [(Int, Int, Int)]
trojkaty = [(a,b,c) | c <- [2..], b <- [2..c-1], a <- [2..b-1], a^2 + b^2 == c^2]

main = do
  print $ take 5 trojkaty
```

Answer (score 2):

This will try infinitely many values of `c` for `a=1` and `b=1` before it even tries `b=2`.

One alternative possibility is to enforce that `c >= a >= b`:

```
 [(a,b,c) | c <- [1..], a <- [1..c], b <- [1..a], (a^2)+(b^2)==(c^2)]
```

Answer (score 2):

Just for fun:

```
Prelude Data.Universe> filter (\(a, b, c) -> a^2+b^2 == c^2 && all (>0) [a,b,c]) universe
[(3,4,5),(4,3,5),(6,8,10),(8,6,10),(5,12,13),(12,5,13),(9,12,15),(12,9,15),...
```

This requires the [universe](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/universe) package.

Comment: Oh, you can do so much better with `universe`! Copy most of the logic from the `Rational` instance to produce the coprime naturals, use Euclid's theorem to get all the primitive Pythagorean triples, and then you just need to take the product with the universe of positive integers to get all the triples.

Comment: @dfeuer That's almost certainly much faster, but it's also much less concise and less obviously correct, which may be characteristics worth paying attention to for beginners!

Answer (score 0):

For completeness, the *other* possibility is to use a so-called "diagonal monad", which tries the possibilities in a different order. There are a couple of libraries out there to do this.

(But for what you're trying to do, the accepted answer is probably much simpler / easier.)

Answer (score 0):

Several suggestions used code like:

```
[(a,b,c) | c <- [2..], b <- [2..c-1], a <- [2..b-1], a^2 + b^2 == c^2]
```

Small improvement, since code is already limiting the choices for a, b, and c, may as well take stock of common knowledge that smallest triplet is a=3, b=4, c=5 resulting in:

```
[(a,b,c) | c <- [5..], b <- [4..c-1], a <- [3..b-1], a^2 + b^2 == c^2]
```

If you care about the "order of presentation", you might need to try something different.